# Copied my WordPress site to localhost now the theme does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

I made a local copy of a WordPress site. I can get into the WordPress dashboard fine. The problem is that our custom WordPress theme is not working, I get:

> **localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500**

Im using WAMP, if that helps.
When I change to any other random theme it works fine.

Comment: Have you made sure to update the URLs inside your WordPress database referencing to your live site. You can do this by running an SQL query in phpMyAdmin. and setting the local DB in your `wp-config.php`?

Answer (score 1):

open your .htaccess file in the root of the wordpress copy and update it

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /           // update this line 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]         // and update this line
```

update the the two lines refers above to the new local url

like that

```
RewriteBase /localhost/foldername/
..
..
..
RewriteRule . /localhost/foldername/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the theme you want to use and then go the permalink settings and save them.